# Why there is a need of approximate solution for 0-1 Knapsack, if input values are high?

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, approximation

On Geeks for Geeks [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polynomial-time-approximation-scheme/), It is mentioned that *" if input values are high, then the solution for 0-1 Knapsack becomes infeasible and there is a need of approximate solution."*

---

And in the approximate solution i.e FPTAS solution, the values corresponding to weights are modified in this way :-

> k  = (maxVal * ε) / n
>
> val'[i] = floor(val[i] / k)

And then the same DP based solution is applied.

---

My Doubt is that, the complexity of actual DP based solution of 0-1 knapsack depends on weight of knapsack and No. of items. It doesn't involve values, then why if values are high then we need approximate solution ? And is doing this makes the complexity of approximate solution better than the actual solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. I think the correct sentence is "if input **weights** are high, then the solution for 0-1 Knapsack becomes infeasible and there is a need of an approximate solution."

In my opinion, in the GeeksforGeeks post "input values" means "all numbers which are given in the input"; it includes both weights and values.